# why is first letter dead in react-hook-form input

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

i need help to understand why the first letter in the simple input component is not registered.

I've created a simple controlled input from the examples but  its not working properly.

i created an example for you https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9zezqx

```
const App = () => {

const { register, handleSubmit, watch, errors, reset, control, formState } = useForm({ mode: 'onChange' });

console.log(errors)
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(() => console.log("submit"))}>
            <Controller
                as={TextInput}
                name="firstname"
                defaultValue=""
                control={control}
                inputRef={register({ required: true, minLength: 8 })}
                hasErrors={errors.firstname !== undefined}
            />
            <br/>
            <Controller
                as={TextInput}
                name="hobby"
                defaultValue=""
                control={control}
                inputRef={register({ required: true, minLength: 8 })}
                hasErrors={errors.hobby !== undefined}
            />
            </form>
      </div>
    );

}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));



import * as React from 'react';

export const TextInput = (props) => {
  return(
    <>
    <input    
      type="text"
      name={props.name}
      value={props.value}
      onChange={props.onChange}
      ref={props.inputRef}
     />
     {props.hasErrors && (<h2>errors!!</h2>)}
     </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

okay i found the bug causing it in 'onBlur' aswell

```
reValidateMode: 'onBlur'
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using an uncontrolled input. If that's the case use `defaultValue` instead of `value`.

[Reference](https://react-hook-form.com/faqs#:%7E:text=React%20Hook%20Form%20is%20based%20on%20uncontrolled%20inputs%2C%20which%20means,for%20the%20initial%20input%20value.)

Answer (score 1):

Swap the mode to `onBlur`, this will improve the performance, will trigger only when the user leaves the field, which is suppose to happen, and also does not swallow the first input.

`onChange` skips the first letter, because the default value will be used for the initial onChange call, which is empty.

Comment: i prefer onBlur, but the problem still occurs there after you have blurred and not fulfilled the requirements for the validation of that field, and you erase everything and try to type again, checkout my link and see for yourself

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem here, you are try to use Controller with register:

https://react-hook-form.com/api#Controller

```
<Controller
  as={TextInput}
  name="hobby"
  defaultValue=""
  control={control}
/>
```

or

https://react-hook-form.com/api#register

```
<TextInput inputRef={register} />
```

Comment: There is no "inputRef" in your second link?

Comment: because it's a MUI prop

Answer (score 0):

If you're running into this issue while unit testing, make sure you're using the latest `@testing-library/react` and `@testing-library/user-event`.  I was having issues with version 13 of each, but once updated to 14 problems went away like magic