# Dynamic form is not working properly on click of add

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating a dynamic form where I have on click of add creating a new element every time, it is working fine till here.

- I have a save button on click I am getting all the data and need to
  do the further process.
- When I click on save I am doing the validation using [React-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/).
- So first time when the fields are empty I click on save and it shows the error (fields can not be empty)
- Then when I type inside the input field it is not taking the first character I press it is taking the second one.
- Same happens when I click backspace after typing a word, the last character it is not deleting.

**What I am doing**

- Below is my onchange, I am passing three things, **e,index and name**

  ```
   const handleInputChange = (e, index, name) => {
   const { value } = e.target;
   console.log(name);
   const list = [...inputList];
   list[index][name] = value;
   setInputList(list);};
  ```
- My HTML

  ```
   < input
     type = "text"
     placeholder = "Display Name"
     name = {
       `employees[${i}].firstName`
        }
     className = {
       errors.employees &&
       errors.employees[i] &&
       errors.employees[i].firstName ?
       'form-control error_input' :
       'form-control'
     }
     onChange = {
       (e) => handleInputChange(e, i, 'firstName')
    }
      value = {
       li.firstName
       }
     ref = {
    register({
       required: 'First Name is required',
    })
  }
  ```

  />

**The issue**

- Click on **Save** first time when Input field is empty.
- Type **Test** -- it wont take t as first time need to press t two times
- Once Test is typed press backspace to delete it will delete tes but to delete T need to press two times.

I just want to know what is the issue, The code I have written I think I have not missed anything.

[My working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-wood-sjg3gq?file=/src/App.js:1127-1776)

Comment: Checkout how to use the [`useFieldArray`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usefieldarray) hook, from the same library, for such a use-case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some researches, I changed
value={li.firstName} to defaultValue={li.firstName}
And it seems to work :)

The link here for reference
[why is first letter dead in react-hook-form input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61141922/why-is-first-letter-dead-in-react-hook-form-input)

Answer (score 0):

just need to focus on the input if the Input field is empty.

In your react component create one more handler for save

```
 const handleSave = () => {
    const name_field = document.getElementById("name_field");
    const nameVal = name_field.value;
    if (nameVal.toString().trim().length < 1) {
      name_field.focus();
    }
  };
```

demo link https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-breeze-hhlfqx?file=/src/App.js

Comment: No I think you did not get the issue, the issue is why it is not allowing to delete the last character or type the first character, Save is always working fine. The demo link still show the same issue

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to debug without the complete code.
You are missing to expose the values of `errors`, `i',` employees`, and that 'Save' feature.
As it is, I can't reproduce the issue.

Having said so, you might want to re-consider using indexes to identify elements in an array. Elements can shift positions, so usually, you will have inside each object a unique id and employ a `.find()` or `.filter()` to track the correct element, which is less prone to mistakes.

Comment: Hi, I have shared the code `sandbox` link please check once, it has my full working code.

Comment: As someone already stated, it has to do with controlled and uncontrolled inputs. Adding `defaultValue` instead of `value` should fix your issue.